# Cloud function triggered by firestore, path gets changed on deployment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a Cloud function written in Python and deployed with Cloud console which is triggered whenever a document is added to a subcollection.

I have specified the path as
`users/{userID}/contactDump/{dumpID}`
which should mean that whenever a new document is added to the `contactDump` subcollection for any user, the function should trigger.

According to [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore), this is a valid path structure. Their own documentation has the following

> `users/{username}/addresses/{addressId}`: valid trigger. Monitors all
> address documents.

But whenever I deploy the function (which happens fine) the path gets changed to just `{dumpID}`

N.B the same happens if I try to deploy a function triggered on `users/{userID}` , after deployment the path gets changed to just `{userID}`

Comment: I understand that the Cloud Function gets deployed, so the trigger initially works, but after the deployment the path is changed? Also I would like to know which trigger type are you using? Could you please share a code snippet of it to be able to better understand your scenario and trying to reproduce it.

Comment: @Vicky that's correct. It appears to deploy fine but then the trigger path is changed. I am using the default python code for the actual function. Because I am creating the function on the cloud console there is no code being written to configure the trigger. I am using the Cloud Firestore, Create trigger type. I have also tried it with the "write" trigger type and the same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

This issue only happens in the Cloud Console, and it's easy to reproduce by creating a new function with a Firestore Trigger with the following set up:

[image: set up]

Once the function is deployed, the trigger section shows the path is not the one added during the function trigger creation, but the one shown is `{addressId}`.

[image: result]

After getting this result, it made me think that is the same issue you are facing, because although using different Event types, the Document path seems to be changed and only shows the last part of the path we entered in the first place, in this case `{addressId}`.

For this, as you said that the the function was working fine, I wanted to get the Cloud Function data performing a GET request using the API Explorer from the [Cloud Functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2F%3CPROJECT_ID%3E%2Flocations%2F%3CFUNCTION_LOCATION%3E%2Ffunctions%2F%3CFUNCTION_ID%3E%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22eventTrigger%22%7D) where in the request parameters I added the Cloud Function created details.

After executing the API call the response will contain the [`eventTrigger`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#eventtrigger) with the full trigger path.

In the example before, the result is:

```
{
  "eventTrigger": {
    "eventType": "providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create",
    "resource": "projects/<PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/users/{username}/addresses/{addressId}",
    "service": "firestore.googleapis.com",
    "failurePolicy": {}
  }
}
```

The “eventTrigger” from the response contains the original path, `users/{username}/addresses/{addressId}`, not the one displayed in the console.

This makes me think that the reason why we see only the shortened path in the Cloud Console doesn’t mean that it has been changed, apparently it is only showing the part after the last “/” slash of the path, even though the path present in the Cloud Function is longer.

Since this looks like an issue with how the console displays the path, I've raised this [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/211101180).

If you need to recover the original path, you can use the API, or the `gcloud` tool:

```
gcloud functions describe FUNCTION_ID --format 'value(eventTrigger.resource)'
```

Comment: Hi @Vicky thank you for your detailed answer and the effort you've gone to. Interesting to see that the path appears unchanged in API Explorer. However, my function does not work. It deploys fine but does not get triggered.